# Convergence of a series question: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{3/2}(-1)^n}{3n^3-(-1)^n}$

Tags: calculus

Given the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{3/2}(-1)^n}{3n^3-(-1)^n}$$
Does it converge? Diverge? Absolutely converge? Converge but not absolutely?

I tried using the square-root-test, but the limit at infinity of $\sqrt[n] a_n$ is 1 , the sequence $a_n$ obviously converge to 0 ... I think that the sequence itself converges because of Leibnitz theorem regarding series with alternating signs. But how can I show that it does not converge absolutely ? 
Am I right regarding the usual convergence using Leibnitz?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$u_n=\frac{(-1)^nn^{3/2}}{3n^3-(-1)^n}$$
so 
$$|u_n|\sim_\infty\frac{1}{3n^{3/2}}$$
hence the series $\displaystyle \sum_nu_n$ is absolutely convergent by comparison with a Riemann series so it's convergent.

Comment: You're welcome.